# Java RegEx single quote in searched text fails pattern

Tags: java, regex

When my text has single quotes, the pattern fails.

I was trying to resolve it with `\\Q` and `\\E` like in Perl but that failed the compilation of the pattern.

e.g.

for pattern `"(?i)Name is\\b(\\w+)\\b"`

if text is `"My name is Foampile X"`, I get a match.  But for `"My name is 'Foampile'"` I don't get a match.

What can I do to regard single quotes wihin text like any other character?

Comment: Word boundary is the boundary between word characters `A-Za-z0-9_` and non-word characters (characters besides `A-Za-z0-9_`). Therefore, your regex won't work.

Comment: What do you want to match in case of `"My name is 'Foampile'"`?

Answer (score 1):

I find it odd that you get a match in any case, because you disregard the space before `Foampile` (`\b` does not consume a character). Note that `\w` does not match quotes, but only `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. So depending on whether you want do include the quotes or not you could try one of these:

```
"(?i)Name is\\W+(\\w+)"
or
"(?i)Name is\\W+?('?\\w+'?)"
```

If you want to assert that the name is separated by exactly one space, regardless of quotes or not, these could be simplified to:

```
"(?i)Name is '?(\\w+)'?"
or
"(?i)Name is ('?\\w+'?)"
```

**And** if your question actually means that you have only been testing without quotes, but your actual goal is to accept names in quotes only, you can leave out all those `?` behind `'`.

However, the very first variant would work regardless of any non-word characters delimiting the name from the rest of the sentence.

Answer (score -1):

The `\w` character class is any letter.  You will need to expaned your regex to include other possibilities:

```
"Name is [\w']+"
```

This gives the regex a possible set of values to expand, including letters or quotes.  It is not a precise match to enforce a correctly-quoted name, however.  That would look more like:

```
"Name is ['"]?[\w']+['"]?"
```

Comment: there will still be no word boundary between the space and `'`

Comment: Please test and write the regex properly.

Comment: you also forgot the capturing group

Comment: Can you provide the error in the regex?  Granted it was simplified from the OP's original regex, however I was attempting to show the difference.  Doesn't seem to warrant a down-vote...